# Babel not transpiling Expo module with Mocha test

Tags: javascript, react-native, mocha.js, babeljs, expo

When running a unit test with Mocha we are getting the following token exception which points to Babel not transpiling.

```
node_modules/expo/src/Expo.js:2
import './environment/validate';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

The mocha test points to a file that imports `Constants` from expo

```
import { Constants } from 'expo'

const config = Constants.manifest.extra
```

This is how the mocha opts and babel are configured

`test/mocha.opts`

```
--recursive
--require babel-register
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
```

Dependencies

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
    "jest-expo": "^24.0.0",
    "mocha": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sinon": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "dot-object": "^1.7.0",
    "expo": "^24.0.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-24.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

We are running

```
yarn mocha
```

Comment: Hi @ptimson, did you able to run `mocha` test

Answer (score 1):

I just faced a similar error - many of my suites would break after I used `Expo.AuthSession` in a single file.

I fixed my issue by adding

`jest.mock('expo', () => ({
  AuthSession: {
    getRedirectUrl: jest.fn(),
  },
}));`

to my global mock file.